# jQuery animating table tbody tag

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, jquery-animate

I have this code which works:

```
    $('a.click_more').click(function() {
            $(this).parents('table.city_table').children('tbody').toggle();
    });
```

I'm trying to create a nice smooth animation to show and hide the table elements. I tried this but it does the same as the top code albeit with a little delay. Probably the half second duration I've set.

```
    $('a.click_more').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('table.city_table').children('tbody').animate({height:'toggle'}, 500);
    });
```

Has anyone accomplished animating table rows, cells, columns, etc or have any suggestions?

I've created a jsfiddle if anyone is looking to play around with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/BHqSM/1/

Comment: Is your jQuery successful? If so, what's the question?

Comment: What kind of "nice smooth animation" are you looking for? Fade in/out? Slide up/down? Or what?

Comment: Just a standard slide up/down animation.

Comment: I've updated the question with a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `slideToggle()` function:

```
$('a.click_more').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('table.city_table').children('tbody').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Tried that too. Produces the same results as the second string of code.

Comment: Try adding 'slow' as the duration. I edited my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Also, no luck. Would it help if I provided my table structure too?

Comment: Couldn't hurt, add that in to your question

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use tables instead of divs?

Comment: It was easier to get the design cross-browser compatible. Also, I wasn't aware the cells needed to animate.

Comment: Gotcha, well you're going to continue to have issue animating the table properly as it stands. If you can, I would just switch to divs instead of tables. You can keep trying to modify the jQuery to get the result you want, but if the animation is essential, you'd be better offer changing it from a table to divs.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't mention what kind of transition you are looking for, it is hard to give you a good example. jQuery does however provide a couple of transitions for you to use out-of-the-box. You could for instance use either [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) to fade the element in/out or [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to slide the element up/down, instead of your `.toggle()` that just switches the display between block and none.

Comment: I've tried them all. I just want the basic click slide to show/hide animation. The issue is that it's not working with tables. I figured if I could toggle the with I could append animation. I mean tables with no width or height set transform to the content around it and conform to the browser window on the fly so why couldn't they animate too.

Answer (score 0):

Table elements do not animate well and there is no getting around it. The only smooth method for animating rows for example is to wrap inner td content in div's and animate the div's